# chain reorged during section processing

Tags: go-ethereum

Previously i was to start my geth network but suddenly i m getting  error="chain reorged during section processing". [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a high likelyhood that you are running a [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) `v1.9.0` or below as your base. Well the issue seems to have been resolved with the release of `v1.9.0`.

The problem which is a chain indexing issue immediately after some reorgs is addressed here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/19748

Tests fix: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20497

Comment: I'm getting this error with geth version 1.9.10 on private network.

Comment: Have you tried the above fix?

Comment: If this issue fixed in v1.9.0, then I should not see the issue in v1.9.10. Could you please explain more about the fix that I can apply?